# What is the opposite of EOMONTH() in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

What is the opposite of EOMONTH()? I am trying to find the beginning date of 12 months ago.  Would it be EOMONTH(Current Date,12)-1?

Any direction would be great. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the opposit function is STARTOFMONTH:

```
=STARTOFMONTH('Date'[Current Date])
```

If you want to get the first day of the month 12 months ago:

```
= STARTOFMONTH ( DATEADD ( 'Date'[Current Date], -12, MONTH ) )
```

This measure will return the first date of the same month a year ago (i.e., for 2018-09-22, it will return 2017-09-01). Current month is included, so you will get a total of 13 months. If you need only 12 months total:

```
 = STARTOFMONTH ( DATEADD ( 'Date'[Current Date], -11, MONTH ) )
```

If you are trying to compute something over a rolling 12 months period, this article should help:
[12-month Rolling Average in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/rolling-12-months-average-in-dax/)

Comment: STARTOFMONTH() is opposite function for ENDOFMONTH() not for EOMONTH()

STARTOFMONTH() will give you the first date in the current transaction scope, not the first day of month

Comment: @RADO first, I deleted my comment as it sounded unfair, sorry about that. Also, looking closer I assume that 'Date' is a date table (contiguous dates), in which case your formula would work assuming that 'Date' also encompasses the previous year. Still, EOMONTH mentioned in other replies looks like a more universal answer.

Comment: @Christophe - thank you. My reasoning was that the EOMONTH is essentially a syntax sugar for ENDOFMONTH + DATEADD, so naturally (for me at least) the opposite of that is STARTOFMONTH + DATEADD. I agree though that the same goal can be archived in many ways, and you should use whatever comes as most intuitive to you.

Answer (score 5):

To find the beginning of a month, go to the end of the month before and add a date to it  (not sure if I understand the question)

```
Start of month one year ago = EOMONTH(TODAY(),-13)+1
```

Comment: This is the one that has worked for me. Can any one confirm if any of the DAX formulas in the accepted answer still work as of today with the latest version of Power BI desktop?

Answer (score 3):

In DAX, you could also use

```
= DATE(YEAR(Dates[Date])-1, MONTH(Dates[Date]), 1)
```

This backs up one year, keeps the month, and returns the first day of that month.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight opposite function for EOMONTH() in DAX. But you can still use EOMONTH() to get the first date of a month.

Last date of a month

```
= EOMONTH(Leaves[LeaveStart]
```

First date of a month

```
= EOMONTH(Leaves[LeaveStart],-1)+1
```

You can also just use 1 in place of date to get first day of a month, like:

```
= DATE(YEAR(Leaves[LeaveStart]), MONTH(Leaves[LeaveStart]), 1)
```

Please note that STARTOFMONTH() is opposite function for ENDOFMONTH() not for EOMONTH().